# Couldn't match expected type [Int] Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, fold, type-mismatch

I am new to Haskell so I don't quite understand most of its errors. I have encountered an error trying to make a higher order function that uses `foldl()` to read a list and then multiply it by 2 (it automatically reverses it) and I use another another `foldl()` just to read it, in so reversing it to its original order.

I would be thankful for any help I receive.

**here's the error**

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’
                  with actual type ‘t0 Integer -> [Integer]’
    • Probable cause: ‘foldl’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘reverses’, namely
        ‘(foldl (\ acc x -> (2 * x) : acc) [])’
      In the expression: reverses (foldl (\ acc x -> (2 * x) : acc) [])
      In an equation for ‘multthr’:
          multthr = reverses (foldl (\ acc x -> (2 * x) : acc) [])
   |
16 | multthr = reverses(foldl(\acc x-> (2*x):acc)[])
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**here's the source code**

```
reverses::[Int] ->[Int]
reverses = foldl(\acc x-> x:acc)[]

multthr::[Int]->([Int]->[Int])
multthr = reverses(foldl(\acc x-> (2*x):acc)[])
```

Comment: Can you please format the code as code? Select it and press Ctrl+k

Comment: So how about pondering `Probable cause: ‘foldl’ is applied to too few arguments` a bit?

Answer (score 3):

You need to *compose* your two foldl's with `(.)`, instead of applying one to the other:

```
reverses :: [a] -> [a]
reverses = foldl (\acc x-> x:acc) []

---- multthr :: [Int] -> ([Int] -> [Int])  -- why??
multthr :: [Int] -> [Int]
---- multthr = reverses (foldl(\acc x-> (2*x):acc)[])  -- causes error
multthr = reverses . foldl (\acc x-> (2*x):acc) []
```

so that we have

```
> multthr [1..5]
[2,4,6,8,10]
it :: [Int]
```

`(.)` is the functional composition, defined as `(f . g) x = f (g x)`.

Instead of doing the two `foldl`'s you can do one `foldr`,

```
mult2 = foldr (\x r -> (2*x) : r) []
```

but then this is nothing else but, simply, `map (2*)`.